# Delphi 7 - Some Errors of VMProtect Implementation

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want to use [VMProtect's Markers](http://vmpsoft.com/support/user-manual/working-with-vmprotect/preparing-a-project/using-markers/) to mark blocks of the code containing string constants that should be protected.

```
uses VMProtectSDK;

VMProtectBegin(MARKER_NAME);
...
VMProtectEnd;

// DELPHI FUNCTION EXAMPLE :

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 VMProtectBegin('Test marker');
 if StrToIntDef(Edit1.Text, 0) mod 17=13 then
  MessageDlg(VMProtectDecryptStringA('Correct password'), mtInformation, [mbOK], 0)
 else
  begin
   MessageDlg(VMProtectDecryptStringA('Incorrect password'), mtError, [mbOK], 0);
   Edit1.SetFocus;
  end;
 VMProtectEnd;
end;
```

I tried to implement it, but I got some errors:

```
[Error] Unit1.pas(xx): Unterminated string
[Error] Unit1.pas(xx): ')' expected but identifier 'Krypt1' found
[Error] Unit1.pas(xx): Unterminated string
[Error] Unit1.pas(xx): Missing operator or semicolon
[Fatal Error] Project1.dpr(5): Could not compile used unit 'Unit1.pas'
```

How to resolve this problem ? Can I asking you to teach me how to write the right line of code [or an example].

My implementation in my Delphi 7 code :

```
procedure TForm1.IdMappedPortTCP1Execute(AThread: TIdMappedPortThread);
var Payload, Host, Header, Krypt1, Krypt2:String;
begin
 VMProtectBegin
 ('
Krypt1 := EncryptString('website.com', 'pwd');
Krypt2 := EncryptString('website.net', 'pwd');
 ');
VMProtectEnd;
      if (pos('CONNECT',athread.NetData)<>0) or (pos('HTTP',athread.NetData)<>0) then begin
      if host.Text = 'Host' then begin
          Payload := 'GET http://'+Krypt1+'/ HTTP/1.1'+#13#10;
          Host := AddHeader(AThread.NetData,'Host: '+Krypt2+''#13#10);
          AThread.NetData := Payload+Host;
          end;
     end;
end;
```

I would appreciate any help.

Cheers,
RzV

Comment: The link you provided shows exactly how to call it from Delphi code, with a specific code example. (It's between the two images.) It's very clear that the code you posted is not valid Delphi code (you can't pass two lines of source code as a function parameter the way you've done here). Read the linked page carefully, and study the code it provides, which does indeed encrypt embedded **string constants** - it does not encrypt **variables** in the way you're attempting to use it, because the content of those variables isn't known at compile time..

Comment: Thank you. So, can you help me to write a delphi7 function based on the VMWare above to use in my code ?

Comment: Can you explain how VMWare has suddenly appeared. Could you also recognise that you asked about a compilation error. I hope you don't expect us to write your program for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
VMProtectBegin
('
Krypt1 := EncryptString('website.com', 'pwd');
Krypt2 := EncryptString('website.net', 'pwd');
');
```

As the compiler says, this is an unterminated string. The quote opens a string which must be terminated on the same line. There is no syntax for multi-line strings. On top of that, you need to escape quote characters that appear in string literals.

You were trying to write something like this I guess:

```
VMProtectBegin
('Krypt1 := EncryptString(''website.com'', ''pwd'');'+sLineBreak+
 'Krypt2 := EncryptString(''website.net'', ''pwd'');');
```

That will compile but I don't expect it will do anything useful. You are expected to pass a marker name to `VMProtectBegin`. It's not at all clear to me that it makes any sense to pass a string containing Pascal code.

Perhaps what you need is this:

```
VMProtectBegin(nil);
Krypt1 := EncryptString('website.com', 'pwd');
Krypt2 := EncryptString('website.net', 'pwd');
VMProtectEnd;
```

Comment: Note that the question asks about a compilation error and that's what I've attempted to answer.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Your first syntax gives me [a lot of errros](http://pastebin.com/a76TJg4Y). And the 2nd, no error found, but VMProtect unable to hide and protect my string, because of the **nil** command.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to escape the quotes. I've done that now. If you need help with the use of VMProtect, ask the vendor for support. I think I answered the question regarding compilation errors, belatedly.

Comment: According to the documentation, passing nil will suffice. Did you read the documentation?